# Cannot access URL from the browser laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to remove index.php from localhost:8081/paymentclone/public/index.php/authenti‌​catio‌​n/login and still access the url like localhost:8081/paymentclone/public/authenti‌​cation/login

Answer (score 1):

To remove the "index.php" suffix from the end of your Laravel applications url, use one of the two methods below.

Method1. At the minimum use the following code and put it in your "public" folder inside an htaccess file. Make the public folder the root of your application.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Method2. If you do not have access to change you application's root folder to public, put the following code in your application's root directory(which presumably is the one where public is contained in) inside of a .htaccess file.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```

> http://www.laminsanneh.com/blog/post/49/laravel-htaccess-how-remove-indexphp-url